Difference between two primes and Riemann Hypothesis
Assuming that $p_{n}$ is a prime number appearing in the index $n$ in the serie of primes, Cramer showed that the difference between a prime and the next is $O(\sqrt{p_{n}}log(p_{n}))$ meaning:
$$p_{n+1}-p_{n}=O(\sqrt{p_{n}}log(p_{n}))$$
Assuming Riemann Hypothesis. Article: Some Theorems Concerning Prime Numbers.
My question is, Are the two equivalent? Or maybe, assuming that the difference between two primes are some $O(f(p_{n}))$ then RH follows.
On that note, is there any way to see the proof of Cramer?

No they are not equivalent - note first that already it is known that the density hypothesis implies the result above at least in the slightly weaker form $p_{n+1}-p_{n}=O(p_n^{1/2+\epsilon})$ while also it is known that unconditionally $p_{n+1}-p_{n}=O(p_n^{.525})$ as per the result of Baker, Harman, Pintz.
Also it is actually believed that the true difference between consecutive primes is far lower than what can be obtained on RH, namely $p_{n+1}-p_n=O((\log p_n)^2)$ and a lot of supporting results (conditional on RH) are known - see Granville's survey
Incidentally, a proof of Cramer's result by a simpler method is given in his $1936$ paper On the Difference Between Consecutive Numbers Theorem $1$ while Ingham in the paper linked below gives a sketch of an argument too.
So to sum it up results of the type $p_{n+1}-p_{n}=O(f(p_n))$ are much weaker than RH when $f(x)=x^{1/2+\epsilon}$ and quite stronger than what can be obtained on RH when $f(x)=x^{\epsilon}$ or even $\log^2 x$. The reason for this is clear - RH and its quasi-variants (no zeroes with real part greater than $\alpha$) and even quasi-versions of the Density theorem as recently proven by Guth and Maynard in their groundbreaking paper give powerful results on the total number of primes in short intervals $(p_n, p_n+p_n^{\theta})$ (they are many!) while analyzing $p_{n+1}-p_n$ requires the existence of just one prime in $(p_n, p_n+p_n^{\theta})$
Note:
The density hypothesis is $N(T,\sigma)=O(T^{2(1-\sigma)+\epsilon}), 1/2 \le \sigma <1$ with $N(T, \sigma)$ as usual being the number of zeroes of zeta with real part at least $\sigma$ and it is implied by the Lindelof Hypothesis $|\zeta(1/2+it)|<<_{\epsilon}t^{\epsilon}, t \ge 1$ as Ingham proved a long time ago, while of course LH is widely seen as much weaker than RH.

Do you have source for the statement $p_{n+1}-p_{n}=O\left(p_{n}^{\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon}\right)$ as well?

the paper by Ingham linked above proves the result that the density hypothesis implies $p_{n+1}-p_{n}=O\left(p_{n}^{\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon}\right)$ (and that the density hypothesis - and quasi-variants are implied by Lindelof and quasi-variants); now of course on RH we know directly that $\pi(x+x^{1/2+\epsilon})-\pi(x)=x^{1/2+\epsilon}/\log x+$ error so trivially the above follows by applying it to $x=p_n$; afaik the best unconditional result as of now is $.525$ exponent
